# Differentiable functions $f'(x)=f(-x)^4f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, functional-equations

Find all differentiable functions $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=1$ such that $f'(x)=f(-x)^4f(x)$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $f^4(x) = f(f(f(f(x)))$ or $f^4(x) = \left(f(x)\right)^4$?

Comment: $f(x)f(x)f(x)f(x)$

Comment: Where did the question originate from? What have you tried?

Comment: i can't understand $f(-x)$

Comment: Just a method is enough for me, not the whole solution

Comment: $f(-x)$ is basically the function $f(x)$ but each $x$ is replaced with $-x$.

Comment: i haven't met $f(-x)$ in a differential equation before and i got confused

Comment: Then consider the cases where $f$ is even and odd. If the former then $f(-x)=f(x)$, meaning the differential equation becomes $f'(x)=f^5(x)$. If it is odd, then $f(-x)=-f(x)$, so $f'(x)=f^5(x)$, which leads you to the same equation!

Comment: that is an excellent idea

Comment: It may be trickier when $f$ is neither... (like $e^x$)

Comment: $f$ is infinitely differentiable

Comment: any idea then? what could someone do eventually? How can i solve the equation?

Answer (score 5):

The defining relation $f'(x)=f^4(-x)f(x)$ implies that $f$ is continuously differentiable (in fact it's even $C^\infty$).

Setting $-x$ in the relation $f'(x)=f^4(-x)f(x)$, one gets $\forall x, f'(-x) = f^4(x)f(-x)$.

Multiplying $f'(x)=f^4(-x)f(x)$ by $f^3(x)$ yields $$\forall x, f'(x)f^3(x) = f^4(-x)f^4(x)=[f^4(x)f(-x)]f^3(-x)=f'(-x)f^3(-x)$$

that is to say $x\mapsto f'(x)f^3(x) $ is even.

Therefore, $\displaystyle \int_{-x}^xf'(t)f^3(t) dt = 2\int_{0}^xf'(t)f^3(t) dt$, and since an antiderivative of $f'f^3$ is $\displaystyle \frac{f^4}4$, this implies $$\forall x, f^4(x)+f^4(-x)=2$$

Replacing $f^4(-x)$ in the defining relation, one gets $$\forall x, f'(x)=2f(x)-f^5(x)$$

By Picard–Lindelöf theorem, this non-linear differential equation (with initial condition $f(0)=1$) has a unique global solution. Using a computer or other means, one finds that  $$x\mapsto \frac{\sqrt[4]{2} e^{2 x}}{\sqrt[4]{e^{8 x}+1}}$$ is a solution of the differential equation, thus it must be the only one.

Conversely, it's easily checked that $x\mapsto \frac{\sqrt[4]{2} e^{2 x}}{\sqrt[4]{e^{8 x}+1}}$ is indeed a solution to the original functional equation.

Comment: For example, if we assume that $f$ is even, then $f'(x)=f^5(x)$. Can we solve then the previous equation?

Comment: @John It seems that the question you asked is way beyond your reach. Anyway, I think I found the only solution to your problem: the function $$x\mapsto \frac{\sqrt[4]{2} e^{2 x}}{\sqrt[4]{e^{8 x}+1}}$$

Comment: maybe, that's why I asked.

Comment: You could also say that it is a Bernoulli equation and consider $g(x)=\frac1{f(x)^4}$ which obeys a linear DE.

Comment: @LutzL how do you prove that $f$ is never $0$ ?

Comment: As usual, you first note that $f=0$ is a solution, but not the required one, and then that because of uniqueness no other solution can cross it.

Comment: @John As the answer proves, there is a single function satisfying the conditions you require, which is not an even function. So if you require that the function must be even, there is no solution.